# Not record celery task parameter in djcelery

Tags: python, django, passwords, celery, djcelery

I used django + celery + python + djcelery + flower for my development.  In the view of django. I did something like:

```
def handle(req):
   task_name.apply_async(args=(req.POST['username'], req.POST['password'], 'p1', 'p2'), queue='x')
```

everything works well.

But when I check the celery flower,  I found the username/password is there.  when I check djcelery in django admin,  the username/password is there too.

So my question are:

1. can we make the parameter just in memory so that no people can see
   them?
2. I want to purge the existing task log in flower, can I?

Update:

I think the args are captured by djcelery, since I find out these data are stored in djcelery_taskstate.

Update:

- Djcelery use celerycam to capture these information and store them in backend and show them in django admin.
- The flower, I think, use some similar method to capture these information and show them in flower page. But the following way can prevent flower from capturing some sensitive data.   http://flower.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#format-task
- I still not find out a way to disable celerycam capture these data..

Update:

finally,  I fix the celerycam with mysql trigger. whenever it stores the password into database,  I used trigger to erase the passworsd

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure how to remove the username and password from the flower screen, but if you want to remove or purge the task which is being displayed, then you can just go ahead and restart flower.

All the existing\completed tasks in flower will disappear from the list.

Comment: thanks,  this does works!  but I still need a solution that the args will be not logged.  btw, I found this may be helpful for other peoples for this case.   http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.1-archived/reference/celery.task.builtins.html#celery.task.builtins.backend_cleanup

Comment: You could try shifting the these params from the args (or from kwargs) and function params. I can only see kwargs and args in the flower dashboard.

Comment: sorry, I can't understand you.  do you mean change the way of invoking celery task?   If so, could you give an example.   In my case, flower catch the args, and show it.  that's not what I want.

Comment: so instead of passing args like this:

task_name.apply_async(args=(req.POST['username'], req.POST['password'], 'p1', 'p2'), queue='x')

pass them as follows:

task_name.apply_async(req.POST['username'], req.POST['password'], args=('p1', 'p2'), queue='x')

Comment: Thanks Mighty,  I tried your suggestion, but it raise 'TypeError' directly.  In [4]: tasks.add.apply_async(args=(1,2)).get()
Out[4]: 3
In [5]: tasks.add.apply_async(1, args=(2)).get()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a023b58b970d> in <module>()
----> 1 tasks.add.apply_async(1, args=(2)).get()

TypeError: apply_async() got multiple values for argument 'args'

Comment: hi Mighty:  I found the following way can fix this issue.  http://flower.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#format-task